# Google Maps Reverse Geocoding API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get correct Lat Long for an address for following address using google map api.

it is eliminating hotel name from formatted_address and I am not getting desired lat long.

Expected Result : (Latitude: 3.171632 | Longitude: 101.695846)

Actual Result :  ( "lat" : 3.1708103,"lng" : 101.6961378 )

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Vistana+Hotel+Kuala+Lumpur+Jalan+Lumut+Kuala+Lumpur+Federal+Territory+of+Kuala+Lumpur+Malaysia&key=MY_KEY

Output:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Jalan Lumut",
               "short_name" : "Jalan Lumut",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Titiwangsa Sentral",
               "short_name" : "Titiwangsa Sentral",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kuala Lumpur",
               "short_name" : "Kuala Lumpur",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur",
               "short_name" : "Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Malaysia",
               "short_name" : "MY",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "50400",
               "short_name" : "50400",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Jalan Lumut, Titiwangsa Sentral, 50400 Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 3.171799,
                  "lng" : 101.697601
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 3.1698591,
                  "lng" : 101.6954027
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 3.1708103,
               "lng" : 101.6961378
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 3.172178030291502,
                  "lng" : 101.6978508302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 3.169480069708498,
                  "lng" : 101.6951528697085
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJHXuFpCJIzDER0VmfA41SBU8",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Can someone let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: Let's do a sanity check here. Your difference in Latitude here is 0.0008217 and in Longitude 0.0002918. Let's take a detour to [wikipedia][1] and we'll see that 0.0001 is about 10 meters at the equator. Considering that you aren't, and that shrinks the distance, you're pretty close. In fact if you plug in those two latitudes and longitudes you'll see that you're about 200ft off. Why do you need to be so accurate? Could it be the API that is off?


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Comment: Have you tried the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/) (with the hotel name)?

Comment: [This is what I get from the Places API](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?zoom=19&lat=3.17153&lon=101.69596&addr1=Vistana%20Hotel%20Kuala%20Lumpur,%20Off%20Jalan%20Ipoh,%20No%209%20Jalan%20Lumut,%20WP%20Kuala%20Lumpur,%2050400%20Kuala%20Lumpur,%20Malaysia&place=1) (seems to not quite match the map tiles)